# Set background-image to a blob: URI

Tags: css

I have a background image stored in a BLOB, say `blob:http://lhost/3dbeb143-a618-46f3-8fa2-25f8dd477692`.

I want to set the `background-image` property of an element to this blob.

I tried setting it to `url("http://isequence/3dbeb143-a618-46f3-8fa2-25f8dd477692")` but it just says `isequence/3dbeb143-a618-46f3-8fa2-25f8dd477692: 404 Not Found`. Clearly it is trying to request that file literally through HTTP.

So how do I go through with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
var tmp_path = URL.createObjectURL('path/to/image.png');
document.getElementbyId('divId').style.background = "url('" + tmp_path + "')";
</script>
```

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob)` -- never knew about this, thanks!

Comment: the assigned value should be "url('" + tmp_path + "')"

Comment: Don't forget
URL.revokeObjectURL(tmp_path);

Comment: @hungryMind Thanks bud! just setting tmp_path was not working for me.