# How to set background image to blob url

Tags: html, background, blob

I am trying to set my background image to a blob url. I have the code

```js
var t = localStorage.getItem('customwallpaper');
var test = t
const blob = new Blob([test], {type: 'text/plain'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url( ' + url + ' )'
```

When I refresh the page, I can go into the console, there are no errors and in the elements tab the background image is set to the blob url. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The local storage variable is a base64 encoded image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer seems quite similar to this question: [Set background-image to a blob: URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810956/set-background-image-to-a-blob-uri)

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41839641/11249686) by [JosephDFGX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7061497/josephdfgx) might work for you:

```html
<script>
    var tmp_path = URL.createObjectURL('path/to/image.png');
    document.getElementbyId('divId').style.background = tmp_path;
</script>
```